# How to Compare SharePoint List item with String Value

Tags: sharepoint-2010

After Migration From SharePoint 2010 to 2013, My Custom Code Of Visual Studio returning error Object reference not set to an instance of an object.When i debug the problem its seems that SharePoint List item is not comparable with string value.So, How can we do this..

I applied Equals Function or ==, Even Firstly Convert the List Item into String and then Compare it..But Error occur same..

Comment: For ExampleItems = (from SPListItem a in b.Items
                   //         where a["Title"].ToString().Trim() == key.Trim().ToLower() select a).FirstOrDefault();

Comment: Here Items return null and i check all the values coming properly.So, plz help me out its urgent